# Как сделать слайдер на подобии этого?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slider

(Слайдер в комментарии) 
Как сделать такой слайдер, но при этом чтобы можно было добавлять 
больше или меньше слайдов? 
Может быть есть библиотеки для реализации такого 
или может у кого есть готовая реализация?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ambassador/pen/yLogrPm

Comment: Здравствуйте, Swiper JS вполне умеет то, что вам нужно, пример описан здесь:
https://swiperjs.com/demos#effect-coverflow
Если добавите ещё изменяющийся фон, как в вашем примере, то получится очень похоже и довольно симпатично